# ng build --prod --aot not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, deployment, build

Here is my local Angular version details.

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 10.15.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.6
```

I'm trying to deploy the production code in the server using the below command.

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

I'm getting a dist folder with all the files. But when I upload the code in the server. It still shows Angular is running in the development code.

Here is my `angular.json` file.

```
    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "matngular": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/homepage.html",
                  "src/login.html",
                  "src/register.html",
                  "src/forgot-password.html",
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/assets/css/prism.min.css",
                  "node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css",
                  "src/assets/css/wizard.css",
                  "src/assets/css/quill.snow.css",
                  "src/assets/css/quill.bubble.css",
                  "src/assets/css/hopscotch.css",
                  "node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css",
                  "node_modules/angular-calendar/scss/angular-calendar.scss",
                  "node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
                  "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
                  "node_modules/videogular2/fonts/videogular.css",
                  "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css",
                  "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css",
                  "src/assets/css/demo.css",
                  "src/assets/sass/app.scss",
                  "src/styles.css"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                  "src/assets/vendor/pace/pace.min.js",
                  "src/assets/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"
                ]
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true,
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "matngular:build",
                "sslKey": "/server.key",
                "sslCert": "/server.crt",
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "matngular:build:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "extract-i18n": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "matngular:build"
              }
            },
            "test": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
              "options": {
                "main": "src/test.ts",
                "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                "scripts": [
                  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                  "src/assets/vendor/pace/pace.min.js",
                  "src/assets/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/assets/css/prism.min.css",
                  "node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css",
                  "src/assets/css/wizard.css",
                  "src/assets/css/quill.snow.css",
                  "src/assets/css/quill.bubble.css",
                  "src/assets/css/hopscotch.css",
                  "node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css",
                  "node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css",
                  "node_modules/angular-calendar/scss/angular-calendar.scss",
                  "node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
                  "node_modules/videogular2/fonts/videogular.css",
                  "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css",
                  "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css",
                  "src/assets/css/demo.css",
                  "src/assets/sass/app.scss",
                  "src/styles.css"
                ],
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico"
                ]
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                  "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**/*"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "matngular-e2e": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "e2e": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
              "options": {
                "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
                "devServerTarget": "matngular:serve"
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**/*"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "defaultProject": "matngular",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "prefix": "app",
          "styleext": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "prefix": "app"
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there any other way to build the app and upload for production?

I have 2 files in environments folder

```
environment.prod.ts
environment.ts
```

Here is `environment.prod.ts` file

```
export const environment = {
production: true,
baseUrl: 'https://app.website.com/api',
domain: 'https://app.website.com'
 };
```

Here is `environment.ts` file

```
export const environment = {
production: true,
baseUrl: 'https://localhost:4200/api',
domain: 'https://localhost:4200'
 };
```

When I run it in the server, localhost urls are called instead of website urls.

Comment: *It still shows Angular is running in the development code.* What does that mean?

Comment: may be issue is with your `environment.prod.ts` file. add your `production` configuration in this file.

Comment: can you post your `environment.prod.ts` ?

Comment: Updated Code @ForestG. Please check it now.

Comment: Your files, the configuration and the cli command are all correct. I suggest you try a different application server, to see if your app get's deployed. I usually test with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), can you check it out and see if it serves your application in prod mode?

Comment: you should set production flag to false in your environment.ts file @Anirudh

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. Does it mean that you still see a logging message telling you that the  application doesn't run in production mode, and that you should call enableProdMode()? If so, do you call enableProdMode()? It's normally done in the main.ts file. What's the content of that file?